# send email on localhost with PHP

Tags: php, html, email, localhost, mamp

I want to send an email on localhost but don't really know how to do it.

I tried some different ways but it doesn't work.

I used PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable as the mailserver but I think thats maybe wrong implemented or so.

Don't know if it's important but I use MAMP.

This is what I currently have:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
  ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
  ini_set("smtp_port","465");
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = "mail account";
  $mail->Password = "password for account";
  $mail->Port = "465";

  $mail->setFrom('receiver mail', 'TEST');
  $mail->addReplyTo('receiver mail', 'TEST');
  $mail->addAddress('recipient mail');
  $mail->Port = "465";

  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = "test";

  // get text from input fields
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

  $bodyContent =
    "<p>Name: " . $name . "</p>
    <p>E-Mail: " . $email . "</p>
    <p>Telefonnummer: " . $number . "</p>
    <p>Adresse: " . $address . $city . "</p>
    <p>Anliegen: " . $textarea . "</p>";

  $mail->Body = $bodyContent;

  if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: *How* does it not work? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, what do you expect to happen? And what does happen?

Comment: Did you read the [Gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) in the PHPMailer docs?

Comment: @JohnConde I don‘t get an error. The function with the echos will not even be executed.. I only want that a mail will be sent to the recipient with all the information out of the input fields after the submit button was clicked.

Comment: @P.Schmidt If neither 'Message could not be sent.' nor 'Message has been sent.' is returned, then you're failing before you get that far.  Check your php error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i finally found the solution. I updated my code to this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sendButton'])) {
  require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
  require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = "secret";
  $mail->Password = "secret";

  $subject = utf8_decode('test');
  $mail->setFrom('secret', $subject);
  $mail->addReplyTo('secret', $subject);
  $mail->addAddress('secret');
  $mail->Subject = utf8_decode('test');
  $mail->Port = "587";
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $sendText = $_POST['sendText'];

  $bodyContent =
    "<p>Name: " . $name . "</p>
    <p>E-Mail: " . $email . "</p>
    <p>Telefonnummer: " . $number . "</p>
    <p>Adresse: " . $address . ' ' . $city . "</p>
    <p>Anliegen: " . $sendText . "</p>";

  $mail->Body = $bodyContent;
}
?>
```

Besides I had to go to myaccount.google.com -> "Sign-in & security" -> "Apps with account access", and turn "Allow less secure apps" to "ON"
Now everything is fine.
Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following two lines :

```
// ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
// ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

And add the following under the line with `$mail = new PHPMailer();`

```
 $mail->isSMTP();
```

And it will work, I have tried it on my laptop on XAMPP.

Comment: You have forgot to set the php mailer to use SMTP

Comment: Hmm, didn't worked for me.. I will try it again later.